# Does not ask for values and uses values from somewhere unknown

Tags: c

I am working on my C Programming language certification and I am doing a challenge as part of the course work. I am using Code::Blocks to build, compile and run the program. The program outputs everything to the terminal like it is suppose to but it is doing 2 things that are baffling me. Even though I don't have to set it up to request user input and was allowed to just automatically feed values into the program for height and width I wanted to push myself and see if I could write the code so when it runs it asks for the user to input the height and width values. well it doesn't do that and even though I did not give any values to feed into the program argument it is still getting numbers from somewhere and I don't know where. It actually has me laughing and scratching my head at the same time. Can anyone tell me where i went wrong on this code. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    double height = argv [0] ;
    double width = argv [1];
    double perimeter = height+width*2;
    double area = height*width;

    printf("Height %f + width %f * 2 = Perimeter %f\n", height, width,
    perimeter);
    printf("Height %f * width %f = Area %f\n", height, width, area);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, it's `char *argv[]`. Second, each `argv[i]` is a pointer to a string, and strings are not implicitly converted to numbers. You need to use one of the string conversion functions, like `strtod` or `sscanf`.

Comment: When I use char *argv[ ] it gives me a compiler error but when I use char argv[ ] it doesn't flag it. Why is it flagging what is suppose to be correct as an error and not the incorrect way.

Comment: When you use `char argv[]`, you should get an error on the line with `main`. But you won't get an error on the `height` and `width` lines because you've told the compiler that `argv[i]` is a single character, so the compiler will implicitly convert that to a `double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you went wrong from the very first line. This is your code, heavily edited to remove the obvious bugs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if( argc < 3 )
    {
          printf("Insufficient number of arguments provided. \n Usage: \"program.exe <height> <width>\"");
          return 1;
    }
    double height = strtod(argv[1], null);

    if (errno)
    {
         printf("height is not a valid floating point number."); 
         return 1; 
    }

    double width = strtod(argv[2], null);

    if (errno)
    {
         printf("width is not a valid floating point number."); 
         return 1; 
    }

    double perimeter = (height+width)*2;
    double area = height*width;

    printf("( Height %f + width %f )* 2 = Perimeter %f\n", height, width,
    perimeter);
    printf("Height %f * width %f = Area %f\n", height, width, area);

    return 0;
}
```

A brief explanation of changes:

1. You are not checking argc for provided number of arguments. Hence the if() I added. Program name is the first argument passed at index 0, so you need to check if at least 3 arguments are provided. I also print program usage.
2. char* are not convertible to doubles by default. Use strtod() for that.
3. perimeter calculation was incorrect since it was doing height + (width * 2) instead of (height + width) * 2.
4. Prototype for main is what I wrote, yours was completely wrong.
5. As a commenter (can't tag while editing for some reason) mentions, it is a very good idea to checking whether string to double conversion succeeded or not.

Comment: Validating the conversions to `double` with, e.g., `if (errno) { perror ("strtod-height"); return 1; }` following each conversion would minimally insure you actually have a valid floating-point number to work with.

Comment: Agreed! I'll update my corrections with your suggestion.

Comment: Good update. Just remember, you don't get extra points from putting it all on one line. It's much easier on older eyes to see nicely indented blocks of code `:)`

Comment: Im getting an error when I try to compile that code telling me: Too few arguments to function 'strtod'

Comment: @WIX10 I have updated my answer to fix that error. Though, **please** show some initiative by resolving compilation errors on your own too. [Here's](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) the documentation for strtod which is how I fixed these two errors.

Comment: Sorry if it doesn't seem like im showing any initiative. i just started into my lectures for C and I haven't even covered half of the fixes your showing me. I didn't think it would be this complicated by taking the harder path. However my head hasn't started spinning yet so I think I will understand this one or another.

Comment: That is why I added explanations for almost all the changes I made. Anyway, have fun with your lectures.

Comment: Thank you so much.